# ajax success callback function redirects to error callback when response json object data count is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to handle a json response using MVC4 api controller which sends object to jstree plugin which binds the response into a tree. Here, response contain a folder list and the httpresponse for the request. The response depends upon the server connection [*take it as one of the conditions*].

**Case 1**: If the server connection is fine, the response is the folder object(`Remember the folder count may be zero, this is where the problem exist, this has to be the success case and message like no leaf node exist has to be displayed but can also be the case of error as explained in case 2`) with httpresponse [*200, OK*].

**Case 2**: When the server connection is not correct, the response is folder object count zero and this has to be handled in error callback function and display error message as server connection error.

So the problem is, when the server connection is fine and the folder object count is zero, the response first goes to the success callback first and then also goes to the error call back which will display an error message as server connection error however i need to display no leaf node exist.

**Code in client side:**

```
    var recreateTree = function (model) {
        $(#treeview)
            .jstree({
                "json_data": {
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": window.virtualPath + "api/myDirectory/TreeViewNodes/",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "data": {},
                        "success": function (data) {
                            do something...
                        },
                        "error": function (data) {
                            do something else...
                        }
                    } 
                 },
              "themes":{......},
               .......... 
            }).bind(........binding code.......);
```

Can anyone help me out with it?

Comment: How's it possible to go error callback when it already have success callback?

Comment: @LolCoder , that is where I'm confused and could not get any solution.

Comment: I strongly suspect in your code.....You can prevent further event-process by aborting current event with e.preventDefault().....

Comment: I got error as `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function, e.preventDefault();` after i tried to use it inside success callback. What actuallay does the e.preventDefault do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misinterpreted your question at first.

The problem seems to be related to the parsing of your data response.

An empty string is considered malformed JSON and triggers an error.

You could try returning '{}' instead of an empty string to solve the issue.

Comment: Tried but didn't work. Once the callback enters the onSuccess, even if you do not use that if condition, the call back redirects to onError itself which is completely undesirable. What might be the problem?

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question at first. I updated the answer.